# SSIS runtime error /missing assembly when task is run

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I couldn't find this error in the community.

"Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebserviceTaskException: Could not execute the Web method.”

The error complains an assembly reference is missing.

Some context: I'm running 1 WebServiceTask and I'm almost certain it's configured correctly since I read the docs. I'm using VS Community 2015 but also have an earlier VS 2013 with an expired developer license.

I think it could be related to this, perhaps SSIS is selecting the wrong assembly reference. Can this be resolved easily by deleting one? If not, how can I safely solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

64-bit Operating System, find the file Microsoft.SQLServer.ManagedDTS.dll in the following path:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies

32-bit Operating System, find the file Microsoft.SQLServer.ManagedDTS.dll in the following path:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies

The folder 90 under Microsoft SQL Server represents SQL Server 2005.

The folder 100 under Microsoft SQL Server represents SQL Server 2008.